# The value obtained when using LibreHardwareMonitor to obtain GPU usage is always 0

Tags: c#

After the introduction of `LibreHardwareMonitor` library, the `IVisitor` class is inherited, and then instantiated.

The following code inherits the `IVisitor` class:

```
public class GetGPULoad :IVisitor
{
    public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
    {
        computer.Traverse(this);
    }

    public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
    {
        hardware.Update();
        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware)
            subHardware.Accept(this);
    }

    public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }

    public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
}
```

The following code instantiates the class and finds the type of GPU hardware and required hardware

```
Computer computer = new Computer
{
    IsGpuEnabled = true
};

computer.Open();
computer.Accept(new GetGPULoad());

foreach(IHardware hardware in computer.Hardware)
{
    if(hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
    {
        foreach(ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors)
        {
            if(sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
            {
                GPUload.Text = sensor.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAmd)
    {
        foreach (ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors)
        {
            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
            {
                GPUload.Text = sensor.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuIntel)
    {
        foreach (ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors)
        {
            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
            {
                GPUload.Text = sensor.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

computer.Close();
```

The returned value is always `0`

Comment: What value are you returning?

Comment: As described in the code, the usage rate of GPU is returned

Comment: SensorType.Load

Comment: Have you debugged this? It looks like you're looping through a load of hardware and then the sensors and updating the same text field each time, so that only the last value will show. Do you want to be adding the values to a list?

Comment: I also suspect you could update your code to use a switch statement where you check on HardwareType and all of your specific cases can be wrapped into one, with a default at the end to handle it if it's not 1 of those 3 types.